# Stacked barplot where each stack layer is subdivided based on an additional variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I would like to create a stacked barplot such that the x-axis is a bin representing the number of unique sample_ids that share a clone, the y-axis is the number of clones in each people bin (I don't really want to show the clone_id, rather the number of clones within each bin category), and each of the clones is actually further divided by the status identity of the cells that make up the clone.  For example, if clone A is made up of 10 cells and 4 are status red while 6 are status blue, I'd like to show that by coloring the clone A layer of the stack 40% red and 60% blue.  The next clone B layer of a stack might be 66% red and 33% blue, etc. I haven't been able to find an example of what I'm looking for, but if anyone knows of a way to split-color each layer individually of the barplot I'd appreciate the advice!

Data example:

```
new_df <- structure(list(clone_id = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104), 
                         sample_id = c(201, 201, 202, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 207, 208), 
                         status = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue"), 
                         bin_id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), 
                         perc_red = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875), 
                        perc_blue = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Stacked barplot code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=clone_id, y=clone_id, x=bin_id)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

I can make a stacked barplot as shown here without that extra level of detail, and with the y-axis a bit messed up as it's trying to identify the clone_id and I just want the number of clones in the bin stack.

I haven't been able to find any examples of the plot type I'm looking for and am at a loss for how to split the color of each stacked layer.

Edit:
I've edited the dataframe to be even simpler above.

I want to show the amount of each layer in the stacked barplot that belongs to 2 set variables (red and blue in this example).  [I am looking for something like this crude powerpoint example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQZnW.png)

Comment: You're much better off using `lapply` with data frames than `apply`, which is made for matrices. `data[ , nums] <- as.data.frame(apply(data[ , nums], 2, as.character))` will be more efficient, more readable, and more generalizable as `data[ , nums] <- lapply(data[ , nums], as.character)`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want. We could do something like `ggplot(data, aes(fill=status, x=sample_id)) + geom_bar(position="stack") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) + facet_wrap(vars(bin_id))`, so we have facets for each `bin_id`, the color corresponds to the red/blue status, and x-axis shows unique sample IDs. Is that close to what you want?

Comment: Your *"the x-axis is a bin representing the number of unique sample_ids that share a clone"* seems risky because what if, within a bin, two different clone_ids have the same number of unique sample IDs. In your sample data, in `bind_id = 2`, you have 3 `clone_id`s, and all three of them have 2 distinct `sample_id`s, so it sounds to me like you want separate bars for each of these 3 clone IDs, not labeled, all at the same `x = 2` value because they have have 3 distinct sample IDs... and this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could simplify your data to, say, 10 or 20 rows instead of 70+, and sketch out what you're looking for? That might make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described sounds to me like a [mosaic plot](https://haleyjeppson.github.io/ggmosaic/index.html). I'm not sure what the expected outcome is for the data you have provided (i.e. what the plot is supposed to look like), but here is my best guess:

Example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

data <- structure(list(clone_id = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 
                                    101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
                                    103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 
                                    104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
                                    105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 
                                    106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107), 
                       sample_id = c(201, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 204, 204, 204, 
                                     209, 209, 210, 210, 210, 203, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 
                                     208, 208, 208, 208, 208, 208, 208, 209, 209, 210, 207, 207, 
                                     207, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 203, 203, 206, 207, 
                                     208, 208, 208, 201, 201, 201, 202, 203, 203, 204, 204, 204, 
                                     204, 205, 205, 206, 207, 208, 208, 208, 208, 208, 208, 204, 
                                     205, 205), status = c("red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", 
                                                           "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                                                           "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", 
                                                           "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", 
                                                           "red", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
                                                           "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "red", 
                                                           "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", 
                                                           "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", 
                                                           "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
                                                           "red", "red"), bin_id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
                                                                                     2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                                                                                     8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 
                                                                                     8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                                                                                     2, 2, 2), perc_red = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                                                                                            0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
                                                                                                            0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
                                                                                                            0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
                                                                                                            0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 
                                                                                                            0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
                                                                                                            0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66), 
                       perc_blue = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                     0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 
                                     0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 
                                     0.65, 0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
                                     0.7, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.6, 0.6, 
                                     0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
                                     0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -71L))
```

```r
data %>%
  mutate(unique_samples = n_distinct(sample_id), .by = clone_id) %>%
  mutate(unique_clones = n_distinct(clone_id), .by = sample_id) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(unique_clones), conds = product(unique_samples),
                  fill = status), offset = 0.05, na.rm = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is this what you're trying to do? If not, what changes would you make to get the 'right' answer?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  This was closest to what I was looking for, but after messing with the data and ggmosaic, I've decided to go an entirely different direction with this plot since I think I was trying to show too many variables all at once.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem; if you 'solve the problem' yourself, and if you can be bothered, please post an answer to your own question illustrating what you ultimately went with. Re https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer